# Как преобразовать объект к заданному виду?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Использую select2 с ajax'ом.
Он требует специфичного вида возвращаемого значения....
При запросе приходит ответ вида:

```
{
        'result': true,
        'errors': [],
        'data': {
            'ITEMS': [
                { 'CODE': '0000121319', 'TYPE_ID': '3', 'VALUE': '15909', 'IS_PARENT': true, 'PATH': [4, 1], 'DISPLAY': 'Иваново' },
                { 'CODE': '0000130232', 'TYPE_ID': '7', 'VALUE': '19616', 'PATH': [15943, 15942, 4, 1], 'DISPLAY': 'Иваново-Вознесенская улица' },
                { 'CODE': '0000132739', 'TYPE_ID': '7', 'VALUE': '20508', 'PATH': [15953, 15952, 4, 1], 'DISPLAY': 'Иваново-Вознесенская улица' },
                { 'CODE': '0001077978', 'TYPE_ID': '7', 'VALUE': '303398', 'PATH': [302284, 83, 1], 'DISPLAY': 'Ивановой улица' }
            ],
            'ETC': {
                'PATH_ITEMS': {
                    '4': { 'CODE': '0000028027', 'TYPE_ID': '2', 'DISPLAY': 'Ивановская область', 'CHILD_CNT': '22', 'VALUE': 4 },
                    '1': { 'CODE': '0000028023', 'TYPE_ID': '1', 'DISPLAY': 'Россия', 'CHILD_CNT': '84', 'VALUE': 1 },
                    '15943': { 'CODE': '0000130025', 'TYPE_ID': '3', 'DISPLAY': 'Родники', 'CHILD_CNT': '270', 'VALUE': 15943 },
                    '15942': { 'CODE': '0000129989', 'TYPE_ID': '5', 'DISPLAY': 'Родниковский район', 'CHILD_CNT': '1', 'VALUE': 15942 },
                    '15953': { 'CODE': '0000132736', 'TYPE_ID': '3', 'DISPLAY': 'Южа', 'CHILD_CNT': '142', 'VALUE': 15953 },
                    '15952': { 'CODE': '0000132735', 'TYPE_ID': '5', 'DISPLAY': 'Южский район', 'CHILD_CNT': '1', 'VALUE': 15952 },
                    '302284': { 'CODE': '0001077937', 'TYPE_ID': '3', 'DISPLAY': 'Саки', 'CHILD_CNT': '143', 'VALUE': 302284 },
                    '83': { 'CODE': '0000028114', 'TYPE_ID': '2', 'DISPLAY': 'Крым', 'CHILD_CNT': '26', 'VALUE': 83 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Вернуть надо объект такого типа:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

Как выполнить преобразование?

Полный код

```
        $('#ORDER_PROP_CITY').select2({
            width : 'style',
            placeholder: function () {
                $(this).data('placeholder')
            },
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            multiple: false,
            language: {
                inputTooShort: function () { return 'Введите название населенного пункта'; },
                noResults: function () { return 'Ничего не найдено'; },
                searching: function () { return 'Поиск...'; },
                inputTooLong: function () { return 'Слишком много символов'; },
                errorLoading: function () { return 'Поиск...'; }
            },
            dropdownParent: $('#ORDER_PROP_CITY').closest('.b-select-section__wrapper'),
            templateResult: this.select2templateResult,
            templateSelection: this.select2templateSelection,
            ajax: {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/bitrix/components/bitrix/sale.location.selector.search/get.php',
                delay: 1000,
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        'select[1]': 'CODE',
                        'select[2]': 'TYPE_ID',
                        'select[VALUE]': 'ID',
                        'select[DISPLAY]': 'NAME.NAME',
                        'additionals[1]': 'PATH',
                        'filter[=PHRASE]': params.term,
                        'filter[=NAME.LANGUAGE_ID]': 'ru',
                        'version': '2',
                        'PAGE_SIZE': '10',
                        'PAGE': '0',
                        };
                        return query;
                    },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.data.ITEMS
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

в каждый data.data.ITEMS нужно добавить id и text

Comment: Не до конца понятно что возвращать.

Comment: Добавил в тест вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let items = [{
    'CODE': '0000121319',
    'TYPE_ID': '3',
    'VALUE': '15909',
    'IS_PARENT': true,
    'PATH': [4, 1],
    'DISPLAY': 'Иваново'
  },
  {
    'CODE': '0000130232',
    'TYPE_ID': '7',
    'VALUE': '19616',
    'PATH': [15943, 15942, 4, 1],
    'DISPLAY': 'Иваново-Вознесенская улица'
  },
  {
    'CODE': '0000132739',
    'TYPE_ID': '7',
    'VALUE': '20508',
    'PATH': [15953, 15952, 4, 1],
    'DISPLAY': 'Иваново-Вознесенская улица'
  },
  {
    'CODE': '0001077978',
    'TYPE_ID': '7',
    'VALUE': '303398',
    'PATH': [302284, 83, 1],
    'DISPLAY': 'Ивановой улица'
  }
];

console.log(items.map(item => ({ id: item.TYPE_ID, name: item.DISPLAY }) ));
```